# Android Bluetooth Advertisements scanRecord zeroed

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing a Bluetooth Low Energy application with Android.

In my scenario there is a sensor that sends advertisements to tell listeners its values. Its kind of beacon broadcast message of iBeacons. On the other side, there is an android app that listens for this messages.

As the data of the sensor is located in the manufacturer data of the advertisement it is forced to read the `scanRecord` parameter listed in [BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback.html)

Testing this with a Nexus 4, Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 & 4 and some Linux machines the `scanRecord` is always set and correct.

Testing it with a Hannspree Tab, an Ionik Tab and a TerraPad (all low-end devices), the `scanRecord` byte array is always zeroed `[0,0,0,0,...]`. But - interesting enough - now and then the name of the device is set, which is also encoded in the advertisement data.

Connecting to the sensor works for both high-end and low-end products.

Does anyone notice this behaviour too? Or has any other suggestions

Comment: I guess its due to lowend devices are lowend devices :). I mean chineese manufacturers could state device has BT LE but its not LE really, thats why it detects the MAC/Name (a part of usual BT functions) of BT deivce and does not catch data. Or such devices has a poor BT drivers, etc. BT in Android is a pain in the @$$ at all. One device works good while the other one - does not and its not even about LE functionality. Two different devices could even not be simply paired sometimes.